# Offset Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim temp_match As Single

Dim mid_value As Single
Dim offset1 As Range
Dim offset2 As Range

Dim off_val1 As Range
Dim off_val2 As Range

temp_match = Application.Match(temp_time, Range("B2:B20"), 1) - 1

Set offset1 = Workbooks("Zero Curve").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B20")
Set offset2 = Workbooks("Zero Curve").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D20")

off_val1 = Evaluate("Offset(offset1, temp_match, 0,2)")
off_val2 = Evaluate("Offset(offset2, temp_match, 0,2)")

mid_value = Application.Forecast(temp_time, off_val2, off_val1)
```

This code shows an error:

> "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Please help.

Comment: Please see [help] and how to add a [mcve] - add enough detail to your question for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues there. Frst you have to use `Set` to assign an object variable. Second you can't refer to a VBA variable in a formula string like that. Third there is no need for `Evaluate` there:

```
Set offset1 = Workbooks("Zero Curve").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B20")
Set offset2 = Workbooks("Zero Curve").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D20")

Set off_val1 = offset1.Offset(temp_match, 0).Resize(2)
Set off_val2 = offset2.Offset(temp_match, 0).Resize(2)
```